# Jquery generate html or php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

it's posible to generate file with using jquery ?
Am make web site maker. On left side i have list of elements like :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Elements                                             Attributes
----------------------------------------------------------------
 ------------ |                                  |  align
 4-col Layout |                                  |  style                             
 3-col Layout |                                  |--------------
 2-col Layout |                                  |  value
 ------------ |    Area where i drag             |  class
 Form         |     drag and drop                |  id
 ------------ |       elements                   |---------------
 Input        |                                  |  onclick
 Button       |                                  |  onpress
 ------------ |                                  |  onBlure
   Etc...     |                                  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

am not looking for code or example i need idea. When some one press on element **button** in right sidebar with jquery i list all button attributes. All work good but when am done and now i want to save my web site i dont have idea how to do that and organise in folders like **css img js index.htm** . its is posible with jquery or php to do somthing like this?
All is almost done just that i cant understand how to do.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: it is posible with jquery or php to do somthing like this? Yes with both together plus some db to stored the information

Comment: Do you want to save the site on the server, or on the client machine? If on the client, JQuery would work, or build it on the server and download it to the client. If you need to save it on the server, you will need to do that in server side code, php from the sounds of it.

Comment: I want when client finish site, he can download full source and he can upload that source on server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to accomplish this and jQuery has some good AJAX functions. In essence you store the information generated by the code into a variable or array and then send that array to a php file/function that writes the data in a DB or File.